# Stop sending email everytime I updates my post

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, wp-mail

My draft posts will have custom field which contains value as email address. So whenever I publish the post, it will send email to the user. It's working fine. However, if I updates the post, it still sends the email again and again. Here is my piece of code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_email' );
function send_email( $post_id ) {

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $subject = 'Your post is published!';
        $message = "Testing!";
        $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>Click here to view</a>";
        $custom_field_name = 'author_email';
        $email = get_post_meta($post_id, $custom_field_name, true); 
        wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );       
    }
}
```

I researched the topic and here is the solution I found here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384299/send-mail-after-publish-post-on-wordpress) but how do I update in my code. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try to use `publish_post` hook instead of `save_post` :  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post : "`publish_post` is an action triggered whenever a post is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish."

Comment: @Jean-RémiLARCELET-PROST this should really be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: @janh I always forget this ! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [{old_status}*to*{new_status} hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#.7Bold_status.7D_to_.7Bnew_status.7D_Hook). And use `draft` and `publish` statuses. This hook will only be executed when your post will change status from `draft` to `publish`.

```
function wpse_288250_send_email( $post ) {

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = 'Your post is published!';

    $message = "Testing!";
    $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>Click here to view</a>";

    $email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'author_email', true ); 

    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );
}

add_action(  'draft_to_publish',  'wpse_288250_send_email' );
```

Keep in mind if you change your post status back to `draft` and again to `publish` e-mail will be send again. To prevent this you can update post meta which will tell you if e-mail was already sent.

```
function wpse_288250_send_email_once( $post ) {

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $email_sent = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'email_sent' );

    if( $email_sent ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = 'Your post is published!';

    $message = "Testing!";
    $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>Click here to view</a>";

    $email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'author_email', true ); 

    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email_sent', true );
}

add_action(  'draft_to_publish',  'wpse_288250_send_email_once' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `publish_post` hook instead of `save_post` :  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post : "`publish_post` is an action triggered whenever a post is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish."

**Updated response** : let's give a try with post status transition, to be sure it's only when the post goes to publish status. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

```
function send_email( $new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if ( $new_status != $old_status && $new_status == "publish") {
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $subject = 'Your post is published!';
        $message = "Testing!";
        $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>Click here to view</a>";
        $custom_field_name = 'author_email';
        $email = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_name, true); 
        wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );       
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: this is working but if i update the post it's still sending email

Comment: I have updated my answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_email' );
function send_email( $post_id ) {

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && ( get_post_status($post_id) !== 'publish') ) {
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $subject = 'Your post is published!';
        $message = "Testing!";
        $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>Click here to view</a>";
        $custom_field_name = 'author_email';
        $email = get_post_meta($post_id, $custom_field_name, true); 
        wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );       
    }
}
```

We could check by get_post_status functions, not to send email again.

Comment: It's not working for me..